# Test failing to assert request correctly even when Postman does it right

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Good night, I'm having a little trouble here. I'm doing TDD for the first time so I don't know the root of this behavior. This post seems long but mainly because I've copied the mayority of the related code.

## Case

Btw, I'm using Laravel as a backend to make an app.

I'm testing that a `User` with the role `admin` can create 'Facility' objects but the rest of the users can't. Something really basic.

## The problem

When testing the endpoint it let users with the role `user` (the regular one) to create the object. But when I tried to test it using Postman it worked as it should be: blocking the request.

To manage acl I'm using Laratrust package (it works well, already test it).

## Code

routes/api.php  // this already has the middlewares: auth & api

```php
Route::post('api/v1/facilities', 'FacilityController@store');
```

App\Htpp\Controllers\FacilityController.php

```php
use App\Http\Requests\Facility\CreateFacilityRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\FacilityResource;
use App\Repositories\FacilityRepository;
use App\Services\ImageService;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

// some code

/**
 * Create a new Facility
 *
 * @param CreateFacilityRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function store(CreateFacilityRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->only(['name']);
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $data['image'] = ImageService::storeAs('images/facilities', $file, 'friendly', $data['name']);

    $facility = $this->facilityRepository->create($data);

    return response()->json([
        "message" => "The facility has been added.",
        "data"    => new FacilityResource($facility)
    ], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

App\Http\Requests\Facility\CreateFacilityRequest.php

```php
class CreateFacilityRequest extends FormRequest {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return auth()->user()->can('create-facilities');
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'  => 'required|string|unique:facilities,name',
            'image' => 'required|image'
        ];
    }
}
```

Finally, this is my test:

test\Feature\FacilityTest.php

```php
/**
     * @test
     * Test for: a Facility can be registered only by an admin.
     */
    public function a_facility_can_be_registered_only_by_an_admin()
    {
        /** Given a correct information for a facility */
        \Storage::fake('public');
        $data = ["name" => "Facility A", 'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('facility-a.jpg') ];

        /** When the request is made by an admin */
        $admin = $this->createUser([], 'admin');
        $response = $this->apiAs($admin, 'POST','/api/v1/facilities', $data);

        /** Then the facility should be registered */
        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_CREATED); // 201

        /** When the request is made by somebody else */
        $data = ["name" => "Facility B", 'image' =>UploadedFile::fake()->image('facility-b.jpg') ];
        $regular_user = $this->createUser([], 'user');
        $response = $this->apiAs($regular_user, 'POST','/api/v1/facilities', $data);

        /** Then the request should be declined */
        $this->assertTrue($regular_user->hasRole('user'));
        $this->assertFalse($regular_user->can('create-facilities'));

        $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN); // 403
        \Storage::disk('facilities')->assertMissing('facility-b.jpg');
    }
```

All the assertions are confirmed except this one:

```php
$response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN); // 403
```

The output is this:

> Expected status code 403 but received 201.
>
> Failed asserting that false is true.
>
> Time: 447 ms, Memory: 20.00MB
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 4, Failures: 1.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

---

When I `dd($response->json())` it return the regular json of a successfull call. But in Postman it returns the correct one:

```php
{
    "message" : "Unauthorized" // with status code 403
}
```

---

## Someone knows why?

---

## Update

protected function apiAs()

```php
protected function apiAs($user, $method, $uri, array $data = [], array $headers = []) : TestResponse
    {
        $headers = array_merge([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.\JWTAuth::fromUser($user),
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ], $headers);

        return $this->api($method, $uri, $data, $headers);
    }


    protected function api($method, $uri, array $data = [], array $headers = [])
    {
        return $this->json($method, $uri, $data, $headers);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) whose `apiAs()` method caches the user's identifier associated to the response on this line:

```
'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.\JWTAuth::fromUser($user),
```

This causes your `$response` variable, the second time you're grabbing the API as a regular user, to return the first cached data for the admin.

I would separate these assertions into separate tests as well as your naming is currently off with `a_facility_can_be_registered_only_by_an_admin()`. `a_facility_cannot_be_registered_by_a_user_that_is_not_an_admin()` may be an applicable name and get around this caching.

Comment: No, when there is no `dd($response)` the `$this->assertStatus(403)` return false (it returns 201). When I do `dd($response)` the returned json is the one that is returned for admin calls, but this should not be the case because this is a regular user without those privileges.

Comment: I'm unsure of which `apiAs()` method you're using, but I bet you that it's caching / saving the first time it's called with the admin related information. I would create a new test (`a_facility_can_be_registered_only_by_a_regular_user()`) testing the specific regular user and assert there.

Comment: You was spot on when suggesting to separate the test in two different tests. Somehow the token (?) was being cached. Please, update your answer to accept it as correct one. Btw, thanks

Comment: Will do! I'll update it now. I'd like to dig in later and investigate too :)